# Find $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos2x)^{3/2}\cos x dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos2x)^{3/2}\cos x dx$$

---

My attempt:
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos2x)^{3/2}\cos x dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1-2\sin^2x)^{3/2}\cos x dx$$
Let $\sin x=t$
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}(1-2t^2)^{3/2}dt$$
I am stuck here.

Comment: What is the dot?

Comment: Multiplication, I'd assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prologue**

*I won't fix the extrema of the integral after my substitution, and I'll leave you the renaming part because it's simple*

**HINT**

From where you got stuck, substitute

$$t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(y) ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{d}t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(y)\ \text{d}y$$

So

$$(1 - 2t^2)^{3/2} = (1 - \sin^2(y))^{3/2} = \cos^3(y)$$

Remembering now that

$$y = \arcsin(\sqrt{2}t)$$

You have to integrate

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\cos^4(y)\ \text{d}y$$

**Useful Reduction Formula**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

You will fine the Cosine reduction formula in the page!